# SumIf in VBA (Conditional on variable)

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I am trying to write two VBA macros:

The first takes a Variable (VariableA) and checks the value of another Variable (VariableB). Depending on the value of VariableB, a multiplier is applied to VariableA. Then the final value of VariableA (with the multiplier) is taken and output into a new variable (VariableC). I have tried an "If Then Else" statement and that doesn't seem to work (most likely because I am doing it incorrectly).

The second macro looks to sum that will take VariableC and sum the variable depending upon the value of VariableB and produce a single output for each occurrence of VariableB.

Multiplier

`VariableA    VariableB    Multiplier   VariableC
 100          1998         1.4           140 
 100          1998         1.4           140
 100          1999         1.7           170
 100          1999         1.7           170
 100          2000         2.0           200
 100          2000         2.0           200`

I have tried to to use SumIfs within VBA but I keep getting an error 13, which I think is coming from the format difference between VariableB and VariableA. Even when I set the two variables to the same format (Integer) I still get the error. When I debug it, it points me towards VariableB as being the issue.

Ideally I am trying to get my final output to look something like this:

`VariableB   SumofVariableC
 1998        280
 1999        340
 2000        400`

I am new to VBA and would appreciate any assistance that anyone could offer. Thank you.

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think a pivot table might provide me part of the solution that I need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the variable multiplier is concerned try using a Select Case

```
Dim Vari as Integer
Dim Multi as Single
Vari = VariableB 

Select Case Vari
    Case Is = 1998
        Multi = 1.4
    Case Is = 1999
        Multi = 1.7
    Case Is = 2000
        Multi = 2.0
    Case Else
        Multi = 1.5
End Select
```

As far as the second issue, I'm not sure I understand whats going on, but it seems that the variables are mismatched. You may need to convert/cast them. An `Integer` data type is not the same as a `Single` data type (for decimals). Use the *convert to integer* **`Cint`** to change the product into an integer before getting to your error point.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table may works on your problem and can give you accurate result with easy navigation on its raw and column

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think a pivot table might provide me part of the solution that I need.

Comment: welcome :)


if this solution helps you, dont forget to vote this up and mark this as an answer ")

Answer (score 0):

## SUMPRODUCT (SUMIF, INDEX/MATCH)

### Excel Solution

- Let's say the upper part is the source and target data. The lower part only displays the formulas used in the 2nd row of the matching columns.
- The image could be used to better explain which data is the source (initial) data, and which is the target (resulting) data e.g. There is data in columns A and B. I have (want to create) a unique list of the data of column B in column F (or in another worksheet in column A or in a comma separated string) and a matching Multiplier in column G. I need to calculate the data ... and copy it into column I. The columns C and D are not needed...etc.
- [Workbook Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ft2a8tmow7gzlum/sumif-in-vba-conditional-on-variable_54873056.xls?dl=0)
  (Dropbox)

**Image**

[image]

**Formulas**

```
=INDEX(G$2:G$4,MATCH(B2,F$2:F$4,0))
=A2*INDEX(G$2:G$4,MATCH(B2,F$2:F$4,0))
=SUMIF(B$2:B$7,F2,D$2:D$7)
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$7=F2)*A$2:A$7*G2)
```